# Diagraming Racks with Visio 2007

Tags: networking, visio

I need to diagram some of my racks with Visio.  The tutorials on the web say to use File :: New :: Network :: Rack ...  But under network I only have 'Basic network Diagram'.  I can find some of the shapes by searching for the rack, but not sure how to load a library that has all of them.  Anyone know where I go to get that stuff?

Comment: I won't post as an answer, because it's not really an answer to your issue, but check out http://www.visiocafe.com for some nice Visio diagrams. In particular, I use a lot of the HP ones: http://www.visiocafe.com/hp.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a default template. You may try reinstalling Visio and making your you install the default templates. If you don't want to mess with that, here is a free-bee from the Tech-Republic.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1051830.html

Comment: I don't the option to install default templates in add/remove features....  Looks like the rack stencil is in `MSOCache\All User\...VisioLR.cab` -- what is this?

Comment: Okay, extracting that cab and then renaming the files with the extension of stencils allowed me to open the stencil.  Somehow I am guessing this isn't the intended workflow?

Comment: lol, well I guess you got it...

Answer (score 1):

Are you going for aesthetics or function?

Unless I'm making something to show off, or for installers to put together right (they like pretty pictures), then I go for utility. For me, that means plain squares, with heights to match the size of the machine. The bonus is that the description of the machine can fill the box (if your diagram is sized such that it's possible, anyway).

Comment: More function, but also speed.  Visio seems to let me label easily, as well as just stretching the server up and down in terms of U's